# Is it possible set a image in a input file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Exists some way to set a image in my input file using `Pure JS` or `JQuery`?

```
<input id="foo" type="file" accept="image/*,video/*" multiple style="display: none;">
```

Comment: The above is the HTML5 approach for accepting image and video files for upload. What do you mean by "set a image in my input file"?

Comment: Short answer is no there is not. Would be a huge security hole if any web site could access your files with no user interaction

Comment: I'm needing set automatically a image in my whatsapp web messages to make a bot.